# Flask-Security Error - NameError: global name 'verify_and_update_password' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-security, flask-mongoengine

Please excuse my ignorance!

I've followed the tutorial for flask-security with MongoEngine and keep getting the following error below when I try to signed in with a registered user account.

> NameError: global name 'verify_and_update_password' is not defined

I've looked through the [Flask-Security utils](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/flask-security-fork/blob/master/flask_security/utils.py) file and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. My code is below:

```
import datetime
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, request, redirect, session, flash
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from mongoengine.document import Document
from mongoengine.fields import *
import bcrypt
import flask_security
from flask_security import Security, MongoEngineUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required, ConfirmRegisterForm
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, current_user, login_user, logout_user

# Create app
app = Flask(__name__)

# MongoDB Configuration
app.config['MONGODB_DB'] = 'testdb'
app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MONGODB_PORT'] = 27017

app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = 'bcrypt'
app.config['SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE'] = True
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True
app.config['SECURITY_RECOVERABLE'] = True
app.config['SECURITY_TRACKABLE'] = True
app.config['SECURITY_CHANGEABLE'] = True
app.config['SECURITY_SEND_REGISTER_EMAIL'] = True

# Flask Mail Configuration
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'my.secureserver.net'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'noreply@mymail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = '3nj8$5jd#9n834'

db = MongoEngine(app)
mail = Mail(app)
login = LoginManager(app)

class Role(db.Document, RoleMixin):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=80, unique=True)

class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    email = db.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    active = db.BooleanField(default=True)
    joined_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    confirmed_at = db.DateTimeField()
    roles = db.ListField(db.StringField(), default=['admin'])

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = MongoEngineUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Adding the following code in the 'class User' just allows me to login without verifying the password:

`def verify_and_update_password(self, password):
        return {'password': self.password}`

Comment: It would be really helpful to have the stack from the `NameError` exception. Also, your link points to a fork. Are you in fact using a fork? What version is it/is it based on?